# Problem on Vectors from "Understanding Pure Mathematics" by Sadler & Thorning

Tags: vectors, proof-explanation

I am reading **[Understanding Pure Mathematics by A.J. Sadler & D.W.S. Thorning](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5018658-understanding-pure-mathematics)** and in Chapter 2 (Vectors) one of the solved examples has got me stuck. Either I need to sleep or there is a typo somewhere in the text.

Please help me understand. Here is the text on page 66 of the textbook:

**EXAMPLE 21**

Find the vector equation of the straight line that passes through the point with position vector 2**i** + 3**j** and which is perpendicular to the line **r** = 3**i** + 2**j** + $\lambda$(**i** - 2**j**).

The given line is parallel to the vector **i** - 2**j**. If the required line is parallel to a vector a**i** + b**j**, it follows that

(a**i** + b**j**) $\cdot$ (**i** - 2**j**) = 0    [for the two lines to be perpendicular]

so, a - 2b = 0

hence, a = 2b

The required line will therefore be parallel to any vector  of the form b(2**i** + **j**).

Taking 2**i** + **j** as one such vector, the required vector equation will be:

**r** = 2**i** + 3**j** + $\lambda$(2**i** + **j**)

Comment: Could you please take the time to explain?

Comment: I thought It's your solution, sorry. OK. of course.

Comment: What part you are stuck

Comment: Which line is perpendicular to which and parallel to which. And how is "The required line will therefore be parallel to any vector of the form b(2i + j)"? The author hasn't given a diagram for this solved example, so I don't know which line(s) or point(s) he is taking about.

Comment: you know the in line $r=a+\lambda\vec{v}$, the $\vec{v}$ is line vector. the line span with this vector.

Comment: In this line $\vec{v}=i-2j$, this not it.?

Comment: Every vector which is parallel with $\vec{v}$ has the form $k\vec{v}$ here $k(i-2j)$. right

Comment: Yes, every vector parallel to $\vec{v}$ has the form $k\vec{v}$. And the vector perpendicular (say $\vec{p}$) to $\vec{v}$ will have a dot product with it as 0. That is, $\vec{p} \cdot \vec{v}$ = 0

Comment: Well, let $ai+bj$ is the required line vector, which is **perpendicular** to the given line so $(ai + bj).(i-2j)=0$, with **dot** product.

Comment: And how do we get the following statements?:

The required line will therefore be parallel to any vector of the form b(2i + j).

Taking 2i + j as one such vector, the required vector equation will be:

r = 2i + 3j + λλ(2i + j)

Comment: We said every line has the form $r=a+\lambda\vec{v}$, the $\vec{v}$ is the line vetor and $a$ is a point on line (not different which that), the $\lambda$ is a parameter for spanning whole line.

Comment: Now, The required line vector is $\vec{v}=b(2i + j)$, it's no metter we take $2i + j$ or $-5(2i+j)$ or $1000(2i+j)$. The point $a=2i+3j$ has given in example statement.

Comment: AHHHHHHHH! We have to substitute a = 2b, and b becomes the scalar quantity that multiplied with (2i +j) to show that it is parallel.

Comment: Thank you so much, @MyGlasses. You are quite the professor.

Comment: You're welcome.